# TestNG XML configuration file DTD "test" tag error

Tags: xml, testng, dtd

I have always getting this error for *test* tag (at line **test** name="Bing-Search-Sample...) in TestNG XML configuration file, when eclipse is trying to validate the XML against its DTD. The file is working fine and seems to have no problems:

> The content of element type "test" must match
>   "(method-selectors?,parameter*,groups?,packages?,classes?)".

XML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="tests" allow-return-values="true"
    verbose="10">
    <test name="Bing-Search-Sample-Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="package.TestFactory" />
        </classes>
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="sample-tests" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <parameter name="testInterfaceXML" value="SearchInterface.xml"></parameter>
        <parameter name="testSuiteXML" value="SearchTest.xml"></parameter>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Since the XML is working fine, I am wondering if there is a problem with TestNG DTD or in the XML file validation with eclipse.

Comment: I get the same exact error when I try to validate the XML at this site: http://www.xmlvalidation.com/index.php?id=1&L=0

Comment: Did you try reordering the tags, as the accepted answer suggests?

Comment: Yes, I tried that.  It had no effect.  I realize my question is not completely baked.  I voted to close my own question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently the order of the elements are important. First comes the parameters, then groups, and classes should be the last element in the test element. That's the correct format of configuration file:

```
<suite name="tests" allow-return-values="true"
    verbose="10">
    <test name="Bing-Search-Sample-Test">
        <parameter name="testInterfaceXML" value="SearchInterface.xml"></parameter>
        <parameter name="testSuiteXML" value="SearchTest.xml"></parameter>
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="sample-tests" />
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="package.TestFactory" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: My testing.xml file doesn't have parameters nor groups.  I have only the 'classes' sub-node.  So, why do I still get this error?

Comment: Maybe add an empty tag for parameters and groups.

Comment: if you have listeners added, they should be added above test name or just below suite name, it will work.

Comment: this method does not prevent the error: The content of element type "suite" must match "(groups?,(listeners|packages|test|parameter|method-selectors|
 suite-files)*)".

Answer (score 8):

Simply change the first line with following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Remove this line :

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
```

It will not show error.

Comment: Removing the line that you mentioned worked for me but what is the reason to delete it?

Comment: It worked for me also -- I am thinking that the version of testng (like the testng plugin for eclipse) needs to be compatible with the version indicated here.

Answer (score 2):

Simpily replace below lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
```

With:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-2.4.dtd">
```

It worked for me.

Reference: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/23176057/web-xml-Element-type-listener-must-be-declared.html

Answer (score 1):

One common use of validation is to ensure that software knows what to expect from the input, so as to guarantee that every valid document will be correctly handled.  There is not always a guarantee that every invalid document will raise an error -- sometimes (as here) some consuming software can in fact handle some documents that aren't valid.

You ask if the fact that the software handles your input correctly means that there is something wrong with the DTD.  Not necessarily:  it's quite often easier to define a strict ordering than to allow for all possible variations in ordering, particularly when the order of elements does not convey information.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check if your testng.xml is correctly formatted, i.e. there are no unwanted characters in it. In my case, I mistakenly put two closing brackets together and tried to execute the testng.xml. It throws the same error.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. This post is better suited as a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the DOCTYPE entire line

Answer (score -2):

If nothing works, try replacing the contents of your file with the content of any other valid testng.xml file. This worked in my case.